# Cross compile Qt onto Raspberry Pi './config' and running 'make -j8' issue

Tags: qt, ubuntu, raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling

I am very new to Qt/Linux and I am currently trying to cross compile Qt 5.11.3 onto a raspberry pi3. I am running into issues when I run the 'make -j8'. If anyone has any Ideas that would be amazing.

The './config' I am using is as follows

> ./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -v -qpa eglfs -no-xcb -system-freetype -skip qtwebengine -nomake examples -nomake tools -fontconfig

```
./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -v -qpa eglfs -no-xcb -system-freetype -skip qtwebengine -nomake examples -nomake tools -fontconfig
```

I am running the './config' and 'make -j8' in qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3 which is in /home/usr/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3

Unfortunately I am running into an issue for the output of 'make -j8' which is as follows

```
make[7]: *** [.obj/qeglfskmsgbmwindow.o] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms'
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'sub-eglfs_kms-make_first' failed
make[6]: *** [sub-eglfs_kms-make_first] Error 2
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration'
Makefile:104: recipe for target 'sub-deviceintegration-make_first-ordered' failed
make[5]: *** [sub-deviceintegration-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
Makefile:99: recipe for target 'sub-eglfs-make_first' failed
make[4]: *** [sub-eglfs-make_first] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms'
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'sub-platforms-make_first' failed
make[3]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins'
Makefile:774: recipe for target 'sub-plugins-make_first' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src'
Makefile:48: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase'
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Updated, What I see when I run just 'make'

```
qeglfskmsgbmwindow.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void QEglFSKmsGbmWindow::resetSurface()’:
qeglfskmsgbmwindow.cpp:58:5: error: ‘PFNEGLCREATEPLATFORMWINDOWSURFACEEXTPROC’ was not declared in this scope
     PFNEGLCREATEPLATFORMWINDOWSURFACEEXTPROC createPlatformWindowSurface = nullptr;
     ^
qeglfskmsgbmwindow.cpp:58:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘createPlatformWindowSurface’
     PFNEGLCREATEPLATFORMWINDOWSURFACEEXTPROC createPlatformWindowSurface = nullptr;
                                              ^
qeglfskmsgbmwindow.cpp:61:9: error: ‘createPlatformWindowSurface’ was not declared in this scope
         createPlatformWindowSurface = reinterpret_cast<PFNEGLCREATEPLATFORMWINDOWSURFACEEXTPROC>(
         ^
qeglfskmsgbmwindow.cpp:61:56: error: expected type-specifier before ‘PFNEGLCREATEPLATFORMWINDOWSURFACEEXTPROC’
         createPlatformWindowSurface = reinterpret_cast<PFNEGLCREATEPLATFORMWINDOWSURFACEEXTPROC>(
                                                        ^
qeglfskmsgbmwindow.cpp:61:56: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘PFNEGLCREATEPLATFORMWINDOWSURFACEEXTPROC’
qeglfskmsgbmwindow.cpp:61:56: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘PFNEGLCREATEPLATFORMWINDOWSURFACEEXTPROC’
qeglfskmsgbmwindow.cpp:62:68: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
             eglGetProcAddress("eglCreatePlatformWindowSurfaceEXT"));
                                                                    ^
qeglfskmsgbmwindow.cpp:65:9: error: ‘createPlatformWindowSurface’ was not declared in this scope
     if (createPlatformWindowSurface) {
         ^
Makefile:2995: recipe for target '.obj/qeglfskmsgbmwindow.o' failed
make[7]: *** [.obj/qeglfskmsgbmwindow.o] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms'
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'sub-eglfs_kms-make_first' failed
make[6]: *** [sub-eglfs_kms-make_first] Error 2
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration'
Makefile:104: recipe for target 'sub-deviceintegration-make_first-ordered' failed
make[5]: *** [sub-deviceintegration-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
Makefile:99: recipe for target 'sub-eglfs-make_first' failed
make[4]: *** [sub-eglfs-make_first] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms'
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'sub-platforms-make_first' failed
make[3]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src/plugins'
Makefile:774: recipe for target 'sub-plugins-make_first' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase/src'
Makefile:48: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gavin/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase'
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Comment: When you use `-j8`, that breaks the build into multiple pieces running in parallel. The advantage of doing that is it can be faster. The disadvantage is it makes the console output impossible to follow because you have 8 separate processes printing at the same time. The part of the output that you've included here does not show us the actual error message, and it will probably be hard for you to sift through and find the real error message. I recommend removing the `-j8` and try to build it again. Then the error will be easier to find in the output.

Comment: So you think I should just type in 'make' into the terminal?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think. Then it will be easier to see what the actual error is.

Comment: So I ran make and this is what showed up

Comment: Oh it doesnt let me pose more than 600 characters or so

Comment: Edit your question and add the extra output there.

Comment: I edited my question, that output isn't the entire output, I can put the entire output in if that would be better, but I just put in what I saw had 'failed' or 'errors' around it

Comment: Great. Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve those errors for you, but now we at least see the real problem. You can try searching online for that specific error to see if anyone else had the same problem.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you for the help!